# How to scan multiple pages to one PDF file using HP Envoy 4500

Tags: printing, hp, pdf

I am using  UBUNTU 14.04 and have a HP Envoy 4500 printer (hplip 3.14.10) connected via USB.
I have a document of about 12 pages. I want to scan them onto a single PDF. I am able to scan each document individually and therefore have 12 individual PDF files, but not to one single PDF. I have searched to web and am now so confused I don't know what to do. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2):

Did you use **Simple Scan**?

If you don't press "New Document" but keep on scanning using the button with the scanner icon, you should be able to save all pages in a single file.

Comment: Thank you Klaus. I downloaded Simple Scan and it works perfectly. I appreciate your help thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue, and I downloaded and now use PDF-Shuffler.

PDF-Shuffler will allow you to quickly and easily merge those separate individual files into a single PDF document.

Also, you can take multi-page PDF documents and split them any way you like just as easily by deleting individual pages.

Once you have added or removed the necessarily individual pages and your file is the way you want it, then you can save your work as a new file.

One thing to be aware of is that PDF-Shuffler is totally free (slash awesome), and as such it has just a few minor limitations: the more pages you merge into a single file, the longer processing time the software takes...be patient...the software is working.

Also PDF-Shuffler seems to max out at around 500 megabytes per single file, so if you had more than 12 pages...say something like 75 pages or more...and the finished product was something like 650 megabytes, then you'd have to split that document into two parts like document part "A" with ~500 megabytes and part "B" with ~150 megabytes (or however you wish to divide the data).

And if you're working with PDFs or any imaged documents, then I also recommend you check out ImageMagick (http://imagemagick.org/) because I use PDF-Shuffler in conjunction with ImageMagick in order to produce my finished product for my job. ImageMagick is straight up ninja from the terminal. These two work great for me.

Good luck!